# Formula referring to cell with another formula - performance optimization

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet with formulas which calculate current data appearing every 1 second through scraping software.

For example, the formula in cell G1 is: `=A1/C1`

In cell H1, I want to add 1 to the value in cell G1. Does it make any performance difference which of these formulas I use?

1)  `=G1+1`

2)  `=A1/C1 +1`

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of thousands of data you won't see any differences in the performance.  Also,  if you have more complex formulas in your sheet then those will limit the performance,  not this one additional division.

Comment: Actually I forgot that I can turn off automatic formula calculation and calculate in VBA to measure execution time. I will post what results I had on some larger amounts of dummy data with similar simple formulas.

Comment: This will depend completely on the specific formulas.  In your example, G1 has already calculated A1/C1, so it's a question of whether it is faster to reference G1 or calculate A1/C1 again.  Even for a specific example, the only way to know will be to test,

Answer (score 0):

I have tested calculation macro execution time for 54K rows on these simple formulas and there is no performance difference, both methods have 0,08 sec on average.